# Is [data] an useful tag? Do we need it? What should we do?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[How to cancel hard disk from wanting to format and how to get my files back?](https://superuser.com/questions/184344/how-to-cancel-hard-disk-from-wanting-to-format-and-how-to-get-my-files-back)
This question is tagged [data](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data) but you know it's about [data](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data) from [hard-drive-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive-recovery).

[Best Light Software to Manage Large Amounts of Data?](https://superuser.com/questions/180036/best-light-software-to-manage-large-amounts-of-data)
This question is tagged both [database](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/database) and [data](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data), but [database](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/database) inherits [data](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data), right?

[How to quicky connect to a sqlite database with OpenOffice.org Base?](https://superuser.com/questions/169963/how-to-quicky-connect-to-a-sqlite-database-with-openoffice-org-base)
This question is tagged [data](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data), but shouldn't it be tagged [database](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/database) instead?

[data](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data)
Shows some more issues of tags that are actually multiple words and might need a hyphen:

- Should [free] + [data] be [free-data] or just [free]?
- Should [data] + [query] be [data-query] or just [query]?
- Should [data] + [validation] be [data-validation] or just [validation]?
- Should [data] + [file] be [file-data] or [data-file] or [file] or maybe nothing or something else?
- ...

Comment: why should database inherit data ? The question can be on installation of a database and your point on database inheriting data becomes moot.

Comment: But that would be a question that doesn't involve [data]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not. I could refer to the data on my drive, the data in memory or various other meanings.

I **do not** consider it to be a meta tag. It is valid within the context of using a computer. Meta tags indicate something outside of the norm, like for example beginner or learning.

**Edit**

Jeff has since deleted the tag and agrees it is a meta tag.

Comment: Okay, it might not be a meta tag... But does the tag itself tell anything extra? Should we be using this tag? One could deduce [data] from the tile or another tag, one could merge the [data] tag with another one (which the user meant in the first place), ...

Comment: @Tom No it's not extra. I see no problem with anyone using this tag, since tags should not appear in titles, and the word data may not be part of the title. Seriously. Drop it. It's one out of a 1000 tags and there are others I would be more worried about. It's been used for a year and until now it's never been a problem. Why now?

Comment: Because I notice the tag now, which has only been used 70 times, and it seems incorrect for most of the questions. But well... I'll leave this question open for others to think about it. It indeed isn't a big issue, but it made me wonder...

Comment: actually you're not using the proper criteria: 1) could you have a question with ONLY this tag and 2) does the tag commonly mean different things to different people -- by these criteria [data] is VERY weak and I would consider it quite close to a meta-tag. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: I have destroyed this tag -- NONE of the posts it contained are now [untagged] which is also strong evidence it was in fact a meta-tag (cannot stand alone)

Answer (score 1):

This tag kept coming back over the years, so it's now been deleted (again) and blacklisted to prevent it from being created again.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :D