# Do [missing] and [disappeared] constitute as meta tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are (currently) 18 questions tagged [`missing`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/missing)

[image]

And 13 questions tagged [`disappeared`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disappeared)

[image]

Am I right in believing that these tags are meta-tags and need to be wiped off ?

Comment: Urgh, you've got be thinking about meta tags now whenever I look at questions. Other suggestions for consideration [`save`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/save), [`open`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/open) and [`bypass`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bypass) - all taken from [one question](http://superuser.com/questions/204698/is-there-any-way-to-open-csv-files-from-a-trusted-source-automatically-bypass-t)...

Comment: These tags keep popping up, and I thought it'd be good to wipe down out in one shot. @DMA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think this is a meta tag based on the [criteria of Jeff Atwood](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1376/is-data-an-useful-tag-do-we-need-it-what-should-we-do) and [his blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> 1) could you have a question with ONLY this tag

I don't think so, [missing-files] and [data-loss] are better than [missing], [data] and [loss].

> 2) does the tag commonly mean different things to different people

Yes, people are left to wonder what is missing.

---

As [disappeared] is just a synonym tag to [missing] it is also a meta tag.

Comment: Those links will come in handy. Thanks @TomW