# Missing and Disappeared tags

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

It looks like meta-tags [missing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/missing) and [disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disappeared) are still hanging around, if they were ever removed ([see the earlier discussion on this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1633/do-missing-and-disappeared-constitute-as-meta-tags)).

I'm happy to go through and remove the tags, unless we want to invoke the [nuclear option](http://homestarrunner.com/sbemail58.html) . . .

Comment: Burn them with FIRRRRE!

Comment: @slhck the proper phrase is "_KILL_ them with fire" ;)

Comment: @nhinkle I know, but I like burning more, killing always sounds so negative :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both well and truly nuked now.

[image: missing]  [image: disappeared]

Comment: A beautiful thing indeed.